# Dockerize two things and use in one directory

Tags: docker

I have an Angular - Flask app that I'm trying to dockerize with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest as node
COPY . /APP
COPY package.json /APP/package.json
WORKDIR /APP
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
CMD ng build --base-href /static/

FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /APP/ .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

On building the image and running the image, console gives no errors. However, it seems to be stuck. What could be the issue here?
Is it because they are both in different directories?
Since I'm dockerizing Flask as well as Angular, how can I put both in same directory (right now one is in /APP and the other in /root)
OR should I put the two in separate containers and use a docker-compose.yml file?
In that case, how do I write the file? Actually my Flask calls my Angular and both run on same port. So I'm not sure if running in two different containers is a good idea.

I am also providing the commands that I use to build and run the image for reference:

> docker image build -t prj .
>
> docker container run --publish 5000:5000 --name prj prj

Comment: How is it "stuck"?  Compiling your Angular app to static files and serving them out of the Flask app as you've done is a reasonable approach (though see @hoverTech's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60426093/10008173), you do need to `RUN` ng build).

Comment: Yes, I was able to serve the app successfully. For some reason, the application did not run on port 5000, but I was successful in running it on port 5001. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In the Angular build first stage of the Dockerfile, use `RUN` instead of `CMD`.

`CMD` is for running a command *after* the final image is built.